# Cocoapods - podspec validates but can't be pushed to repo

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am setting up a Swift framework through CocoaPods.

Goals are:

- Use a private repo for the Podspecs
- Have the framework to be distributed as binary (as opposed to source code)

I've read already the [CocoaPods frameworks](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/), [Making a CocoaPod](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html) plus other references (can't seem to be able to include more than 2 links with current SO reputation but I can point sources in comments).

The Podspec I am using is:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = 'SDK'
s.version          = '0.0.1'
s.summary          = 'My SDK'
s.description      = 'SDKs description'

s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/XXX/sdk'
s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { 'XXX' => 'xxx@xxx.com' }
s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/XXX/sdk.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
s.platform = :ios, '9.0'

s.source_files = 'SDK/Classes/**/*'

s.preserve_paths = 'Frameworks/SDK.framework'
s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/SDK.framework'
end
```

The Pods xcode project was changed to build also i386 arch besides the standard (arm64, armv7).

This spec successfully validates locally with, provided that I copy the SDK.framework file to the /Frameworks folder in the .podspec folder:

```
pod lib lint
```

**Issue: when I try to push the spec to the repo, the validation fails as the output below show:**

```
pod repo push mySDKPrivateRepo SDK.podspec 

Validating spec
 -> SDK (0.0.1)
    - ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.
    - ERROR | file patterns: The `preserve_paths` pattern did not match any file.
    - ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file.

[!] The `SDK.podspec` specification does not validate.
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I make the podspec validation successful when pushing it to repo?

Other notes:

1. Copying the SDK.framework to /Frameworks works manually.
2. If I include a Copy Files build step in the Pods Xcode project the file is not copied.
3. Using CocoaPods 1.1.0.

Comment: @Galazy - did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, the culprit was the project structure itself.

Be sure to check your at which directory you're pointing your source_files to. I've found that maintaining any kind of structure in this way is very difficult and it's easier to include all of your files in a single folder.

```
s.source_files = '<InsertName>/**/Classes/*'
```

Take a look at cocoapods advice on [File Patters](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#group_file_patterns) for some help on this.

By a process of elimination, I would suggest trying to push to the repo commenting out source_files in the podspec first, and work your way forward from there.

Comment: I ended up commenting this line out and it worked with the added ending in terminal of --allow-warnings